# Wrodpress DDOS /xmlrpc.php

Tags: wordpress, ddos

This is what my nginx access.log looks like as I write this times infinity:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2016:00:59:36 -0500] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

I've tried to to put in place the common fix which seems to be inserting the following into my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'remove_xmlrpc_pingback_ping' );
  function remove_xmlrpc_pingback_ping( $methods ) {
    unset( $methods['pingback.ping'] );
    return $methods;
} ;
```

But sadly the above snippet still isn't doing anything, my server has been doing this all day today. And what makes the issue here to me seem odd is the ip is 127.0.0.1

Currently running Ubuntu 14 / Nginx / PHP5 FPM / MariaDB / Varnish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.1 of course is internal. Did you check your cron jobs etc?

For external IP addresses, Fail2Ban is your solution. You match such a log line in Fail2Ban, and Fail2Ban will tell your firewall to ban that IP for the amount of time you specify.

Fail2Ban can be much more useful for WordPress than that alone. It keeps my servers clean in many ways.

Comment: I actually self diagnosed here. Issue 127.0.0.1 is because I wasn't reporting 'Real Ips' in NGINX. Since I have varnish infront that's way I was hitting that issue. After about a hour of going through logs I went ahead and banned 38 or so ips... I though am still in fear of trying to come up with some exception if I see X request in X ms it should auto ban... But I could only imagine the exceptions to the rule I will have with regular users..

Comment: That type of rule based banning is exactly what Fail2Ban does for you. Combing through your logs you should be able to come up with a pattern that doesn't belong to real usage. You can then ban based on that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Jay, I was going to have Fail2ban watch the access.log for these exceptions but I heard this wouldn't be such a good Idea?

Comment: Can't see why that's a bad idea, as that's what it is meant to do. Fail2Ban bans many WP related things for me, from login attempts to spam attempts and everything in between.